# Nativescript-slides slider content overlap

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am creating android native application. I am new in nativescript. I have requirement for create dynamic slide screen with many content in screen and i search in google and i found below link [nativescript-slides](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides/issues/37)

I go through this link and i created below code

slides.html

```
<Slides:SlideContainer angular="true" id="slides" #slides pageIndicators="true" changed="changeSlides">
    <Slides:Slide class="slide" *ngFor="let player of players">
        <Label [text]="player.name"></Label>
    </Slides:Slide> 
</Slides:SlideContainer>
```

slides.component.ts

```
import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("Slide", () => require("nativescript-slides").Slide);
registerElement("SlideContainer", () => require("nativescript-slides").SlideContainer);

export class SlidesComponent implements OnInit {
    players : Array<Player> = [];
    @ViewChild("slides") slides: ElementRef;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.handlePlayer();
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let SlidesXml = this.slides.nativeElement;
        SlidesXml.constructView();
    }
    handlePlayer() {
        //Call api and get data
        this.players = data;
    }    
}
```

But when i execute `tns run android` I got below response(overlap all player name)

[image]

So how can i resolve this issues?

Comment: Use programmatic logic for ading your Slides (as shown here https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-slides) instead of inline *ngFor which is an Angular directive and has different approach for rendering items from the one used in the plugin SLidesContainer

Comment: @NickIliev  thanks for reply but i have too many content in screen so its not possible by logic, only possible by *ngFor but using *ngFor i got overlap all content